# For a planar embedding of a graph G containing at least one cycle, prove that every face of that embedding contains a cycle on its boundary.

Tags: graph-theory

In the notes the professor gave us, it says the method is to prove this by induction on q (number of vertices in G), starting with the base case that G has exactly one cycle, so the embedding has exactly two faces, so that 
$$p + q + 2 =c + 1$$
by Euler's formula, so that $$q = p + c+ 1$$ For the induction step $$q <= p + c+ 2$$ then delete a non-cut-edge.

This explanation is not really detailed and I fail to grasp the details. I understand that the base case is when $$ q = p+ c + 1$$ but fail to see how the induction step works. For instance, if for a graph where $$q<= p+ c + 2$$ and containing only 1 cycle, if we delete the non-cut edge of that cycle, the graph becomes a tree and none of the faces contains a cycle. So what exactly is the induction?

Answer (score 0):

Is this really true of any planar embedding of $G$? For example:

[image]

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the question, but I don't see another way of making it something useful to prove.

Comment: I think it is true for the above example. For the boundary of the outer face it contains the large 4-cycle. For the inner face, the boundary contains the smaller 4-cycle. The face in the middle's boundary contains both the outer cycle and the inner cycle.

Comment: @booya I read the question as asserting that (the vertices of) any face has a cycle that touches the *graph's* boundary. Otherwise all you're saying is that a face is a cycle, which is extremely uninteresting.

Comment: OR, on further reflection, the intermediate face - between the shaded face and the outer boundary - is an interesting example, I guess, of where the vertices around the face **contain** a cycle but the boundary of the face is not itself a cycle. So maybe it's not as uninteresting as I thought.